# .Net 6.0 WPF Click Once Publish error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: wpf, clickonce, publish

Trying to publish a .Net 6 WPF application using Click Once. I get the following error:**System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\bhrob\source\repos\edsexecsln\edsexec.wpf\bin\release\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0\win-x64\app.publish'**

I changed the settings in the publish dialog trying different combinations without success, and always get a version of the above message.  The publish process does not seem to create the **win-x64\app.publish** portion of the path.

Comment: Just spitballing, but have you tried creating the directory yourself to see if that fixes or at least changes the error?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't work for me. I will start a new project and copy over the code, building and publishing as I go, so I can catch the error.  If I get no error, I'll have a new working project.